# Export DXF from QGIS layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, export, dxf

I want to export a **DXF file** from a **QGIS layer**.

Sample code:

```
dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
dialog.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.Directory)
dialog.setOption(QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
DirectoryName = dialog.getExistingDirectory()
layers = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()

for layer in layers:         
     filename = DirectoryName + "/" + layer.name() + ".dxf"    
     QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, filename, "utf-8", layer.crs(), "DXF", 1)
```

Result DXF file is empty.

How can I export as DXF file using either `QgsVectorFileWriter()` or `QgsDxfExport()`?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You mention `Qgsdxfexport()` in your title but have you tried it?  If so, what happened?

Comment: I want to export a DXF file using QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat() or Qgsdxfexport() ... anyway ...... i wish!! search !!! sample Code export DXF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take example on the code in [qgisapp.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/2cbcf74ef2ee6e212ea1dc5fe14da7c4f1a6123d/src/app/qgisapp.cpp#L5717-L5764) and transform it to python as follows (just replace the elements within underscores):

```
dxfExport = QgsDxfExport()

settings = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
# settings.setLayerStyleOverrides( QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection().mapThemeStyleOverrides( _yourmaptheme_ ) )
dxfExport.setMapSettings( settings )
dxfExport.addLayers( _layers_ )
dxfExport.setSymbologyScale( _scale_ )
dxfExport.setSymbologyExport( _mode_ )
dxfExport.setLayerTitleAsName( _title_ )
dxfExport.setDestinationCrs( _crs_ )
dxfExport.setForce2d( _force2d_ )
# dxfExport.setFlags( _flags_ )
dxfExport.setExtent( _extent_ )


dxfFile = QFile( fileName )
dxfExport.writeToFile( dxfFile, _encoding_ )
```

addLayer was causing a crash in QGIS. It has been fixed in QGIS 2.18.17 and QGIS 3.0.
`_layers_` is now a list of `QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer( layer )`

---

Another interesting approach (although not in Python) is that you can run QGIS dxf export from the command line: `qgis.exe --dxf-export file.dxf myproject.qgs`

See the [command line options](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/fi/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html#command-line-options) in the QGIS documentation for a complete description.

Comment: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/11790    QgsDxfExport.addLayers causes crash

Comment: In this cas maybe you can try installing an earlier version of QGIS? @김철진

Comment: I found an issue in the Python bindings. Will try to fix it.

Comment: There are 2 pull requests (QGIS 2.18 and QGIS 3.0) pending which fixe the issue. See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/6323 I will update the code as soon as it's merged

Comment: this is merged and will be release in QGIS 2.18.17 (23.02.2018)

Comment: @Denis Rouzaud - I am very grateful for your kind reply.

Comment: If you are satisfied, can you mark it as accepted?

Comment: It seems crucial to not forget `dxfFile.close()` at the end, otherwise the written DXF file does not open (FME, AutoCAD). [QGIS 3.16]

Answer (score 4):

If I use your code in the **Python Console** with the [QgsVectorFileWriter()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html) class , the value `5` is returned which seems to be a [ErrAttributeCreationFailed](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a3a4405a59d8f8ac147878cae5bd9bade). We could skip the attribute creation using `skipAttributeCreation=True` as a parameter if you don't care for the attributes.

So your final line should read:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, filename, "utf-8", layer.crs(), "DXF", skipAttributeCreation=True)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.!!!
If the layer has a column called 'AAA' and I want to use it as a layer attribute of a DXF file, how do I change the code?

Comment: @김철진 - Not easily unfortunately, I could not find a way to transfer the attributes over as you would using `Project > Export DXF...`.

Comment: Hm...anyway. really. Thank you!!! Do you know a simple sample code that uses QgsDxfexport?

Comment: @김철진 - Apologies but I could not find any sample code online yet, if I do I will post it here :)

Answer (score 4):

Suggested solution: using the ogr library, with this approach it is possible to set the value of the "Layer" attribute of the DXF with an attribute from the inLayer.

```
from osgeo import ogr
import os

# Get the input Layer
inShapefile = "c://gis//wrld.shp"
inDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
inDataSource = inDriver.Open(inShapefile, 0)
inLayer = inDataSource.GetLayer()

# Create the output Layer
outDXF = "wrld.dxf"
outDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("DXF")

# Create the output DXF
outDataSource = outDriver.CreateDataSource(outDXF)
outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer("wrld", geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)

# Add input Layer Fields to the output Layer
inLayerDefn = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(0, inLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = inLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    outLayer.CreateField(fieldDefn)    

# Get the output Layer's Feature Definition
outLayerDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()

for i in range(0, inLayer.GetFeatureCount()):
    # Get the input Feature
    inFeature = inLayer.GetFeature(i)
    # Create output Feature
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(outLayerDefn)
    # Add attribute by index from inFeature to pass to output Layer.
    # Set the field_num (here 2) by the position of the field in the original file.
    outFeature.SetField("Layer", inFeature.GetField(2))         
    # Set geometry.
    geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
    outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)
    # Add new feature to output Layer
    outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
    inFeature = None
    outFeature = None

# Save and close DataSources
inDataSource = None
outDataSource = None
```

EDIT: This can be achieved also by :

```
import subprocess
command = ["C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 2.14\\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe", "-f", "DXF", "output.dxf", "c:\\gis\\wrld.shp", "-sql", "select ISO as Layer from wrld"]
subprocess.check_call(command)
```

For lines use:

```
import subprocess
command = ["C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 2.14\\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe", "-f", "DXF", "output_l.dxf", "c:\\gis\\wrld.shp", "-sql", "select ISO as Layer from wrld", "-nlt", "MULTILINESTRING"]
subprocess.check_call(command)
```

[Note: ISO is a name of a field in wrld.shp]

Comment: I would like to create one DXF file with both point, line, and ploygon.
Is it possible?

Comment: I am very pleased to learn from you. and this case. 
The dxf file has only polygons. 
What if I want to add point data and line data to dxf?

Comment: I'm looking into the matter, nothing in the doc, so I'm imrovising hopefully I'll have an answer today.

Comment: if [a.shp] is point and [b.shp] is line and [c.shp] is polygon .. I wish [D.dxf] including [a.shp] , [b.shp] and [c.shp]]

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for that, will keep trying. Also looking for merge options for dxf

Comment: Did you find any solution for converting shapefiles with different geometry types into one dxf file ?