# Export multiple shapefiles to one DXF file using Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to convert shapefiles into one DXF file using pyqgis, I started with one layer, the problem is that I can't open the DXF file after conversion.
[image: Screen capture when trying to open converted dxf]

I've tried two approaches but still getting the same problem.
First approach: based on this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269960/export-dxf-from-qgis-layer-using-pyqgis)

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFile
dxfExport = QgsDxfExport()
layers=[QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer(iface.activeLayer())]
settings = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
dxfExport.setMapSettings( settings )
dxfExport.addLayers( layers )
dxfExport.setLayerTitleAsName(True)
dxfExport.setDestinationCrs(26191)
dxfExport.setForce2d( True )
dxfFile = QFile( 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test\\file.dxf' )
dxfExport.writeToFile( dxfFile, 'utf-8')
```

second approach : based on this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20734/python-how-to-export-shapely-objects-to-dxf-file)

I converted my shapefile to geojson then used FWtools to convert the geojson file to dxf.

```
ogr2ogr -f DXF test.dxf test.geojson
```

Is it possible to access source code of 'project>DXF export' funcionality ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ogr2ogr with the shapefile?

```
ogr2ogr -f DXF myfile.dxf my_shapefile.shp
```

Comment: Yes I did, the output can't be opened in AutoCAD

Comment: Can you share your shapefile?  If not try exporting the same shapefile using qgis and see if that will export properly to DXF.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work using command prompt but excuting the command in the QGIS python console fixed the problem. The code I used is : 

import subprocess
command = ["C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 2.18\\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe","-f", "DXF","C:\\Users\\Desktop\\output_dxf.dxf","C:\\Users\\Desktop\\b\\input_shp.shp"] 
subprocess.check_call(command) . But I steel can't convert many shapfiles to one DXF file

Comment: You can first merge all shapefile into one (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/merging-multiple-vector-layers-to-one-layer-using-qgis) then export to DXF

Comment: unfortunately they don't have the same geometry type