# Exporting selected features in dxf using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

This code should create a new DXF file for every new features contained in an attribute of a shapefile.

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('LAYER NAME')[0]
filename = 'FILE NAME'

objects = []

for l in layer.getFeatures():
    objects.append(l["ATTRIBUTE NAME"])

object = set(objects)

print(objects)
print(object)

for o in objects:
    layer.selectByExpression("\"type\"= {}".format(o))
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, filename + o + '.dxf', 'utf-8', layer.crs(), driverName='DXF', onlySelected=True, skipAttributeCreation=True)
```

But the following error occurs (the dxf file is created on the computer, but it doesn’t contain any information) :

`(5, "Creation of field ID failed (OGR error: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ID' not created.)")`

As mentioned in this post [Export DXF from QGIS layer using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269960/export-dxf-from-qgis-layer-using-pyqgis), if `skipAttributeCreation=True` is set, no error occurs, the dxf files are created but there’s no information…

```
(0, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the "Select by Expression" line that gives nothing (None)...

```
for o in object:
    layer.selectByExpression('\"YOUR FIELD\"=\'%s\'' % o)
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, filename + o + '.dxf', 'utf-8', layer.crs(), driverName='DXF', onlySelected=True, skipAttributeCreation=True)
```

These lines should work. Unfortunately, you have to keep `skipAttributeCreation=True`, I don't know why...

Comment: Your "Select by Expression" lines work, mine too. But thanks, though.